# When to use HP when attacking a tree?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In my GM book (pathfinder for beginners) there are some stats for environmental things. Doors, walls, trees etc.

A typical tree for instance has 150 HP. I am, however very unsure on when to actually use the HP of that tree when playing with my players.

There was no encounter with monsters, etc. that was long enough where hitting a tree could be properly incorporated (except maybe if one player gone insane :D). Neither would I force my players to start a grind against a tree if they had the intention to chop it down while not in an encounter.

Did somebody successfully used such stats? Same for walls, when players have a weapon that can damage a wall I would not start an encounter with this inert object :)

The HP can be used to indicate the time etc to break it but why the heck has a typical tree a flat-footed value? :D

To clarify the intent of my question: I am asking for people's experience or hints on how the HP of a tree can actually be used in a game in a sense that does not annoy the players.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PCs have been trapped by a horde of orcs at the edge of a ravine, and must chop down a tree to make an impromptu bridge so they can escape, while fighting off those orcs. In this case the HP stat for the tree gives a *de facto* timer for an endurance battle - PCs can't defeat the whole horde, but can they last long enough to escape?

Or, the orcs have reached the Elven Forest Of Mystery, and now *they're* doing the chopping. Can the PCs defeat them before they chop down the Tree of Infinite Magic?

etc. etc.

And sometimes assigning HP to a thing like this is useful as a way of saying "more than your character can get through in a hurry". If you don't give stats, guaranteed some player will decide that his first-level barbarian *should* be able to chop through a tree in one hit. With stats, the GM can just say "okay, but you need to do 150 HP damage", which may avoid a lot of time-wasting argument.

Answer (score 1):

Including objects into an encounter makes it more exciting and unique. Well, tree is a massive object and it is hard to ruin it in several blows, so when would you need to use its HP?

**First**, in any situation when time matters. Either the party needs to chop down a tree before something happens or the monsters are trying to chop a tree down and the party is trying to stop them.

**Second**, you need the HP to adjudicate magic or similar effects. Well, there are not so many spells that are capable of dealing 150 hp of damage to an object, but several spells in a row can do that. Imagine a group of fighters standing under a tree and an elven archer sitting high above the ground hiding in the foliage. What if a 10th level wizard from an opposing party sends three fireballs in a row at the fighters? Will the elf still be hiding safely or the tree will collapse and the elf will fall to the ground?

Or you may think of another situation. A party is trying to cross a chasm by a fallen tree. An opposing wizard casts an *Acid Fog* on the passage. The party decides to retreat and wait until the fog disperses. Will the log be still there when they return? Probably yes, because minimum 12 rounds are needed to deal 150 HP damage with *Acid Fog* (if you roll extremely well) or 21 rounds on average. But if it is still there will the fireball cast by the same wizard at the party crossing the chasm send them flying down along with the remains of the tree?

Besides, you can use logs as beams in structures. And I think it is safe to assume that these will have the same HP as living trees.

HP for walls are even more useful, because there are siege engines in the rules. And siege engines are specifically designed to destroy walls. You can make a good encounter with these. For example, sending a party to destroy a catapult before it breaches the wall and enemy forces rush into the castle.

To give you a real example I'll describe an encounter I've made for a module we've played recently. I've made up a room in a dungeon with a stone block ceiling supported by a whole trunk wooden pillar in the middle of the room. I've placed two groups of zombies in the room. One was commanded to engage anyone entering the room, the other was to start chopping the pillar as soon as anyone comes in. As soon as they would have finished the work the ceiling would collapse burying everyone in the room under the stones. So the party had to decide whether to deal with the group attacking them and risk being buried or try to get around them to attack the chopping group but leave enemy in the back. That definitely added suspense to the encounter.